# Is it possible to return (stream) a response (xml) from django as the output is rendering?

Tags: python, django, dhtmlx

I have a page, which returns 10,000+ records as XML, which takes 7 seconds to return which i'm happy with, as most of it isn't displayed until the user scrolls down.

But my front end has to wait 7 seconds for django to return anything so it can start showing the output, DHTMLX is able to render as data is being received so i was wondering if django can do this and how would I go about it?

tl:dr; I want Django to respond as it renders output, can it? if so How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can't do this with templates, and so you have to move over to HttpResponces and building up your return manually, which may not be worth it for a lot of people.